# Disable notification screen iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

Is it possible to block appearing of notification screen by swiping from top edge of screen on iPhone when my application is in foreground state. Doesn't this break iOS HIG rules?

[image]

Comment: hava a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7759385/how-can-you-disable-the-ios-notification-center-within-your-app?rq=1) please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You don't want to do that.** (And you can't.)

There is a way to keep it from appearing immediately, however: *hide the status bar*. When you do this, the system will first show a little grabby thingy when the user swipes down from the top. If the user swipes again, Notification Center will show.

[image]