# How do you prevent Notification Center in games?

Tags: ios7

In iOS7, swiping up from the bottom of the screen or down from the top of the screen slides a "glass screen" on top of the app you are using. In many games, it is very frustrating.

As a user, you can turn off this behavior in apps, but this is a system-wide change.

Angry Birds has small triangles pop up when a top/bottom swipe is detected, which is not a perfect fix, but something already.

Is there any better solution? What API/call to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've set statusBar is initially hidden to YES in Info.plist , but it failed to achieve the result I wanted.  [Setting UIApplication statusBarHidden to YES does not work in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897983/setting-uiapplication-statusbarhidden-to-yes-does-not-work-in-ios-7) got me the answer I needed:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)])
{
    [self prefersStatusBarHidden];
    [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
}
else
{
      // iOS 6
      [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
}
}

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
  return YES;
}
```

This, as per 21/10/2013, works fine.

Comment: I don't know. If it does, tell us :)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for iOS 11. (I'm trying to get Mini vMac for iOS to actually let me pull down menus without interrupting me with Notification Center).

Answer (score 3):

To get the same behaviour in iOS 11, you must implement `preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures` on your view controller:

```
- (UIRectEdge)preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures {
    return UIRectEdgeAll;
}
```