# Can you / How do you lock In-App Navigation Center access in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, ios7

Title should be pretty telling, but here's a bit more detail. I am working on an app that uses a top to bottom pan gesture a lot, which often times drags down the notification center in inadvertently. Is there any way to disable the Notification Center while my app is running?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this question, and see if you can use the solution provided:

[How do you prevent Notification Center in games?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918427/how-do-you-prevent-notification-center-in-games)