# SpriteKit TouchesMoved and preventing the Pull Down menu iOS

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, touchesmoved

I am using iOS 7's SpriteKit to create a game and have a ship moving up and down the vertical side of the screen in portrait mode reacting to touch in the touchesmoved method.  I am running into a problem because for some reason the pull down menu on the top of the simulator is displaying the menu when I move up close to it with my finger still held down.  The problem seems to only occur in the simulator.  Is there a way to prevent the notification pull down menu from displaying when I touch the screen to move my ship? My method is as follows.

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        CGPoint newPosition = CGPointMake(heroShip.size.width / 2, location.y);

        // stop the paddle from going too far)
        if (newPosition.y < (heroShip.size.height / 2) + 100) {
            newPosition.y = (heroShip.size.height / 2) + 100;
        }
        if (newPosition.y > self.size.height - (heroShip.size.height/2) - 100) {
            newPosition.y = self.size.height - (heroShip.size.height/2) - 100;
        }

        heroShip.position = newPosition;
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Greg

Comment: No one is going to play this on a simulator so if it works on the device you have nothing to worry about

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918427/how-do-you-prevent-notification-center-in-games